# converting decimal-number to binary-number

Tags: c

My program should convert a decimal number into a binary number.
The first for loop is for calculating the binary number.
The second loop puts the msb into the first element of the array.
It is an exercise and the msb has to be in the first element.
I do not understand where the mistake is, help is very much appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

int i;
int bits[16];
int bits_2[16];
int number; 
int decimal; 
int rest;
int msb;
int result=1;

printf( "Input number smaller than 65536: ");
scanf("%d", &decimal);
if(decimal >= 65536) {
printf( "\n\nincorrect input!");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

number=decimal;

for(i=0; result!=0; i++){
    result = decimal / 2;
    rest = result %2;

    bits[i]=rest;
    msb = i;
    return msb;
    }

printf("\n\n %d as binary number : ", number);

for(i=msb; bits[i]>=bits[0]; i--){
    bits_2[msb-i] = bits[msb];
    printf("%d", bits_2[msb-i]);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: One likely problem is `return msb;` inside the for loop. You return from your main function and then the program exits, probably not what you want.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik I don`t get the binary number.

Comment: Why there is return `msb` in for loop? And what does `result = decimal / 2;` mean in the same loop?

Comment: @Jite So I don`t have to return msb to use it in the second loop?

Comment: Also, in the same `for` loop, you are terminating the loop based on `result` going to zero. But `result` is being set to `decimal / 2`, and `decimal` is never changed, so that loop will never terminate once you remove the erroneous `return msb`.

Comment: @haccks It`s for calculating the binary number.

Comment: Read @Dtor; comment. It explains the suicide attempt by that statement.

Comment: A pro tip, write the logic down on a piece of paper first as words, when you get it right, translate it to code and it will be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = number = decimal;

for(bits[0]=msb=i=0; result != 0; i++){
    bits[i] = result % 2;
    result = result / 2;

    msb = i;
}

printf("\n\n %d as binary number : ", number);

for(i=msb; i >= 0; i--){
    bits_2[msb-i] = bits[i];
    printf("%d", bits_2[msb-i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your code with some changes to make it work (you can improve it)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

int i;
int bits[16];
int bits_2[16];
int number;
int decimal;
int rest;
int msb;
int result=1;

printf( "Input number smaller than 65536: ");
scanf("%d", &decimal);
if(decimal >= 65536) {
printf( "\n\nincorrect input!");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

number=decimal;
for(i=0; result!=0; i++){
    result = number / 2; //change this line 
    rest = number %2; // change this line
    number=result; // add this line
    bits[i]=rest;
    msb = i;
 //   return msb; //delete this line
    }

printf("\n\n %d as binary number : ", decimal); // change this line

for(i=msb; i+1; i--){ // change the condition
   // bits_2[msb-i+1] = bits[msb]; // delete this line
    printf("%d", bits[i]);  // change this line 
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have a lot of **useless** variables so this is a **compact** version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

int i;
int bits[16];
unsigned int decimal;
int rest;
int result=1;

printf( "Input number smaller than 65536: ");
scanf("%d", &decimal);
if(decimal >= 65536) {
printf( "\n\nincorrect input!");
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
else
printf("\n\n %d as binary number : ", decimal);

for(i=0; result!=0; i++){
    result = decimal / 2;
    rest = decimal %2;
    decimal=result;
    bits[i]=rest;
    }
i--;

for(; i+1; i--){
    printf("%d", bits[i]);
    }

return 0;
}
```